# Understand Mat in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, mat

I am trying to understand the following piece of code Take from: [Opencv Mat](http://answers.opencv.org/question/19062/how-to-train-my-data-only-once/)
and more precisely this part:

```
Mat labels(0, 1, CV_32FC1);
Mat trainingData(0, dictionarySize, CV_32FC1);
```

From what I understand is that `labels` is equivalent to `std::vector<float>` and `trainingData` is equivalent to `std::vector<std::vector<float>>` and where `std::vector<float>` is of dimension `dictionarySize`. Is that correct?

I am asking this question because I want to convert `bowDescriptor1` which is a `MAT` to `std::vector<float>`

---

Convert `bowDescriptor1`to vector:

```
   std::vector<float> data;
   for(size_t r = 0; r < bowDescriptor.rows;r++)
    {
       for(size_t c = 0; c < bowDescriptor.cols;c++)
       {
          data.push_back(bowDescriptor.at<float>(r,c));
        }
     }
```

Comment: `labels` initially is a "matrix" with 0 rows and 1 column. After that, `push_back` is called to add additional elements of type `float` which means to add another row with a single element to `labels`. So at the end you will have a matrix of size `n x 1` where n is the number of pushed floats. For `trainingData` push_back gets not single floats as input, but new matrices, which means to add those matrices as new rows. So at the end you will have trainigData to be a matrix of size `m x dictionarySize` where m is the number of added matrices.

Comment: If you want to interpret `labels` as `std::vector<float>` you would iterate through the whole matrix (1 element per row I think) and push_back each element to a vector. If you want to interpret `trainingData` as a vector of vector of floats you would create a float vector for each row and push those vectors back to your `vector<vector<float>>`

Comment: @Micka so in the code he's converting Mat dictionarySize to a row which later on is adding to trainingData

Comment: yes I think so (didnt recheck all tbh), have a look at http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-push-back too

Comment: I actually want to convert bowDescriptor1 to a row std::vector<float>

Comment: yes you are right actually bowDescriptor1 = 1 x dictionarySize its a vector yes as you said

Comment: according to this: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html#bowimgdescriptorextractor-descriptorsize the bowDescriptor is a matrix with as many elements as the size of the vocabulary set. I guess they are all in a single row, so you could read them similar to an array and put them into your vector. but that's more a guess than knowledge ;)

Comment: ok, so your question is answered? or do you need help reading from such a matrix?

Comment: @Micka Ys sure if you can. I'll also post how I converted bowDescriptor1 to std::vector<float>. I'll add your response as an answer. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without testing:

from documentation you can see that bowDescriptor seems to be a matrix of size `1 x dictionarySize` http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/object_categorization.html#bowimgdescriptorextractor-descriptorsize

so you have to go through that matrix and save each element (float) to your `vector<float>`

try this code:

```
std::vector<float> currentBowDescriptor;
for(int col = 0; col < bowDescriptor1.cols; ++col)
{
    currentBowDescriptor.push_back(bowDescriptor.at<float>(0,col));
}
```

that's it. push_back those currentBowDescriptor s to another vector if you want.

If you want to save some computation time, you can even initialize the currentBowDescriptor in advance since you know the number of descriptor values (dictionarySize) and access those elements instead of pushing back.

hope this helps.